# Как использовать коллекцию ReactiveList в Avalonia C#?

Tags: c#, mvvm, avalonia, reactive

Создал приложение Avalonia .NET Core MVVM App. После создания в приложении уже был установлен пакет Avalonia.ReactiveUI, я так же установил пакет ReactiveUI  и ReactiveUI.Fody.
После установки перечисленных пакетов в коде появилась возможность использовать атрибут [Reactive]. Я так же хотел использовать коллекцию ReactiveList, но VisualStudio не видит такого типа. Как это испрать? Может быть, у меня не хватает какого-то ещё пакета NuGet или директивы using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тип коллекции устарел. Много лет назад DynamicData была плотно интегрирована в ReactiveUI, а последняя по умолчанию включена в Avalonia.

Сейчас существуют 2 вида коллекций: SourceList и SourceCache. Авторы DynamicData советуют использовать 2ю всегда, когда у нас есть какое-то уникальное свойство, например, Id.

Полезные ресурсы(снизу еще):

1. http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhyRx
2. https://gist.github.com/minhhungit/6df3b90b41dac35452c0eb998f7e84c1

**P.S** Весь код хоть и набирал в студии, но не запускал, но думаю везде рабочий)

Небольшой пример. В главной UserViewModel мы по клику добавляем пользователя, данные улетают в сервис откуда они опять отправляются в другую ViewModel, которая заранее подписалась на изменение коллекции Users(UserService).

```
//Основая модель
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

```
//Сервис и его реализация
public interface IUserService
{
    IObservable<IChangeSet<User, string>> Users { get; }

    void AddUser(User user);
}

internal class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly SourceCache<User, string> _users = new(x => x.Id);

    public IObservable<IChangeSet<User, string>> Users => _users.Connect();

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        _users.AddOrUpdate(user);
    }
}
```

```
//Основная ViewModel для действий с сервисом
public class UserViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly Random _rand = new();

    //К этой кнопки мы привязываемся в Button Command
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddUserCommand { get; }

    public UserViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;         

        AddUserCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(AddUser);
    }

    private void AddUser()
    {
        User user = new()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Age = _rand.Next(1, 50)
        };

        _userService.AddUser(user);
    }
}
```

```
//Другая ViewModel, которая подписывается на изменения сервиса
public class OtherViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<User> _users;

    //К этой коллекции мы привязываемся в View
    //Например, ItemsControl - ItemsSource={Binding Users}
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<User> Users => _users;

    public OtherViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        userService
            .Users
            .Bind(out _users)
            .Subscribe();            
    }
}
```

```
public class OtherViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<User> _users;

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<User> Users => _users;

    public OtherViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        userService
            .Users
            .Bind(out _users)
            .Subscribe();            
    }
}
```

---

Если вы только начали изучать, то не забывайте уничтожать подписки на события(Subscribe). Вам нужно обнаруживать навигацию между окнами. В Prism, если вы его используете в Avalonia, это RegionMemberLifeTime - https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/region-navigation/controlling-view-lifetime.html. В чистом Reactive View должна реализовывать интерфейс IViewFor, а ViewModel IActivatableViewModel. Подробнее: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/

Реактивный подход - это поначалу очень сложно, но благодаря нему можно делать динамичные и удобные приложения!

Пример:

```
//Какой-то сервис с IObservable свойством
public class TestService
{
    private readonly ReplaySubject<int> _number = new(1);

    public IObservable<int> Number => _number.AsObservable();
}

public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    [Reactive] //Обычное Fody свойство
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    [ObservableAsProperty] //То же Fody, но с extension, которое автоматические уничтожает подписку
    public int Number2 { get; }

    public TestViewModel(TestService testService)
    {
        //numberDisp - IDisposable, который нам надо обязательно уничтожить
        var numberDisp = testService
            .Number
            .Subscribe(x =>  Number = x);

        testService
            .Number
            .ToPropertyEx(this, x => Number2 = x);            
    }
}
```